# JavaFX: Delay TranslateTransition

Tags: java, javafx-2

I create some node in javaFX. And I need to animate each node to translate between some point to some point in `Pane` with `TranslateTransition`. But I need to make each of that node move independently using different starting point. How to make this happen? I mean is there any something like Thread.pause in javaFX. I tried using the rough approach like in the code below:

```
    public void mouseRespon(final double x, final double y){
    animasi.pause(); 
    thread = new Thread(
            new Runnable() {                    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int i = 0; 
                    while(threadStatus && i < allList.size()){
                        final int j = i;
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                DynamicsText text = allList.get(j); 
                                TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
                                transition.setNode(text); 
                                transition.setFromX(text.getTranslateX()); 
                                transition.setFromY(text.getTranslateY());
                                text.setDestinyOffset(x, y);
                                text.initCurrentOffSet();
                                double destX = text.getPotitionX();
                                double destY = text.getPotitonY(); 
                                transition.setToX(destX);
                                transition.setToY(destY);
                                transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                                transition.setAutoReverse(false); 
                                transition.setCycleCount(1);
                                transition.play();
                            }
                        });
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(25);
                        }catch(Exception e){}
                        i++; 
                    }
                }
            });
    thread.start();
    animasi.play();
}
```

But I think  that is not a good approach. And actually, when I run that snippet make a program  crash (sometime) .

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you're trying to do, but look at [SequentialTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) which allows you to specify a list of transitions to run one after another. [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is a useful way to create pauses and execute code on the FX Application Thread when the pause is over, if you still need that.

Comment: This is about a small project that you can see in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JYEWo0g_00&list=UUw2ozvdUKUQmQGHLDyHBmgA
and the code I host on github:
https://github.com/gunungloli666/jam_follow_mouse

I tried what you suggest but not make any thing better:
https://gist.github.com/gunungloli666/9579838

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ParallelTransition`.

For each piece that you want to move, create a `SequentialTransition`, a `PauseTransition`, and the `TranslateTransition`. The `PauseTransition`s should be incrementally bigger for each piece, say 0, 25ms, 50ms, 75ms, etc. Add the `PauseTransition` and the `TranslateTransition` to the `SequentialTransition`. Add each `SequentialTransition` to the `ParallelTransition`.

Then play the `ParallelTransition`.

No need to create any `Thread`s or mess with `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: Sory, but i need two instance of animation modify the state a clock simultaneously. First animation to make that clock rotate around a center point,and second animation to make that clock respond mouse movement. With paralelTransition (or any similar javaFX animation) the scenegraph need to complete second animation before continuing to first animation and that make everything thing mess. And with detection of  mouse movement javaFX enggine get confused when mouse move to a new location before completed the last transition.You can try this snippet:https://gist.github.com/gunungloli666/9592813

Comment: Can  I conclude this is some of the weakness of javaFX?
I mean, why i can't modify javaFX scenegraph with multithread?

Comment: I think you can do this just fine. Almost all modern UI toolkits are single-threaded but I don't see why that prevents you doing what you want. You can create one animation that performs the rotation and another animation in response to the mouse event. You may need to add multiple transforms to the same node, which you can do using Node.getTransforms(). My advice would be just to think about Animations: if you're manipulating threads at all to do this you're probably doing it wrong :).

Comment: Yeah, I made this work using the techniques I described. This looks too much like a homework problem for me to post the code though.